# how to retrieve from a specific XML element in java

Tags: java, xml

What line code can I add in my method that will only modify the tagname "location" as LONG AS IT CONTAINS A SPECIFIC information under the node named "address?" So if i update "color" or "size" then I can tell the nodeList: "change these values only if it contains 123 Main Street in "address." I've tried all types of "equal etc." note: I created an object that i use object.getAddress as my variable that i want to check against.
XML has 50 entries:

```
<location>
    <address>123 Main Street</address>
    <color>red</color>
    <size>large</size>
</location>


public void changeValue(Document doc, String oldValue, String NewValue) throws         Exception {
    Element root = doc.getDocumentElement();
    NodeList childNodes = root.getElementsByTagName("location");
    for (int i = 0; i < childNodes.getLength(); i++) {
        NodeList subChildNodes = childNodes.item(i).getChildNodes();
        for (int j = 0; j < subChildNodes.getLength(); j++) {
            try {
                if (subChildNodes.item(j).getTextContent().equals(oldValue)) {
                    subChildNodes.item(j).setTextContent(NewValue);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
    File file = new File("XMLDatabase.xml");
    save(file, doc);
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting an error are you not able to replace the oldValue with newValue? Please explain?

Comment: If I am not wrong you want to change the colour or size if you can match the address. If this is what you want in the if loop try initializing a local int variable and assign j's value to it and simply set the new values of colour  and size as subChildNodes.item(local int+2).setTextContent("value you want to set"); Does this help? If not clarify?

Comment: i don't get an error. Yes, you got it right by saying that i want to change colour or size as long as the address matches. I actually have an object that is global which contains the address i want to check against. If i don't check it against the object then I can't control the loop as it updates other nodes I dont want changed.

Comment: Ok if I am not wrong you use object.getAddress to get the address of the address to be matched, which you send to String NewValue during method call and change the colour if that matches? If that is the case the solution of my previous comment will work

Comment: yes, that is right. thank you. I will try. I was hoping to see it in a line code because i have been trying this for hours. LOL

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps!

```
for (int i = 0; i < childNodes.getLength(); i++) {
        NodeList subChildNodes = childNodes.item(i).getChildNodes();
        for (int j = 0; j < subChildNodes.getLength(); j++) {
            try {
                if (subChildNodes.item(j).getTextContent().equals("123 Main Street")) {
                    int temp=j;
                    subChildNodes.item(temp).setTextContent("value you want to set");
                    subChildNodes.item(temp+2).setTextContent("value you want to set");
                    subChildNodes.item(temp+4).setTextContent("value you want to set");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
}
```